# Падеж, в который необходимо поставить приложение

Tags: приложение

Как правильно:

1. Носить фамилию Свантессоны;
2. Носить фамилию Сватенссонов?

Comment: А других варинтов нет? Тогда эти - оба хуже.

Comment: Кстати, а где дело-то происходит? Если в Исландии, то вообще - глупость. У них нет фамилий.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что здесь должен использоваться именительный падеж — независимо от формы определяемого слова (*фамилия*).

[**носить**](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Nosit-17278.html), нсв. кого-что.
6. (со словами: имя, фамилия, название и т. п.). Иметь, называться. *Корабль носил название "Отважный".*

Носить фамилию (чью?) — отца, матери, деда; носить фамилию (какую?) — Васильев, Лебедев, Морозов...

Свантессон, Робертсон, Якобсон — эти фамилии одинаковы и для мужчины, и для женщины.
Правильно: носить фамилию Свантессон.

Итак, о соседях. Эти соседи **носили фамилию Каретниковы.** И принадлежали к канцелярскому миру. Сам товарищ Каретников был бухгалтер. [М. М. Зощенко. Возвращенная молодость (1933)]

Мало того, что двое из самых любимых артистов советского кино **носят фамилию Быков**, мало того, что оба стали замечательными режиссерами, так и сниматься Леонид Федорович и Ролан Антонович начали в одном и том же 1954 году. [Владислав Быков, Ольга Деркач. Книга века (2000)]